# Silverlight, bug with Dataform when adding and then removing entity with PagedCollectionView?

Tags: silverlight, ria, dataform, pagedcollectionview

I'am using the silverlight 4 dataform on a view with the MVVM pattern (and the "simple mvvm toolkit") and RIA services (and EntityFramework on server side).

My dataform is Bind to a PagedCollectionView on the viewModel. The logical context is "A 'Region' has * 'Territories' and a 'Territory' is linked to a 'Region'" (I recreate the original problem on Nothwind database to explain it).

```
 <toolkit:DataForm Name="DataForm"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding RegionTerritories}" 
                              CurrentItem="{Binding TerritorySelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              AutoGenerateFields="True" 
                              AutoEdit="True"
                              AutoCommit="False"
                              IsReadOnly="False"
                              Margin="0,10,0,0" EditEnded="DataForm_EditEnded" 
                              DeletingItem="DataForm_DeletingItem" AddingNewItem="DataForm_AddingNewItem"
                              CurrentItemChanged="DataForm_CurrentItemChanged" />
```

The code of my View Model to load entities on the pagedCollectionView :

```
this.RegionTerritories = new PagedCollectionView(this.CurrentRegion.Territories.ToList());                
            this.RegionTerritories.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(RegionTerritories_CollectionChanged);
```

I watch changes on the PagedCollectionView to update my DomainContext (throught "serviceAgent") by listening the "CollectionChanged" event :

```
private void RegionTerritories_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    Territory territory = item as Territory;
                    if (territory != null)
                    {
                        this.regionServiceAgent.InitializeNewTerritoryAndAddToDomainContext((Territory)item);
                        territory.Region = this.CurrentRegion;
                        this.CurrentRegion.Territories.Add(territory);                            
                    }
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    Territory territory = item as Territory;
                    if (territory != null)
                    {
                        if (this.CurrentRegion.Territories.Contains<Territory>(territory))
                        {
                            this.regionServiceAgent.MarkForDeleteTerritory(territory);
                            this.CurrentRegion.Territories.Remove(territory);                               

                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            //case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
            //    break;
            //case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
            //    break;
        }
    }
```

And here is my problem : if "this.CurrentRegion.Territories" is empty (no Territories present), and if I add an item and then directly cancel it, the cancel action make me pass on "case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:" as expected. Everything works until 'this.CurrentRegion.Territories.Remove(territory);' this line of code create a "'System.NullReferenceException' occurs on System.Windows.Controls.Data.DataForm.Toolkit". The Exception appends excatly on "this.RaiseDataMemberChanged("RegionID");" when "Territory" entity is doing internal update : .

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Obtient ou définit la valeur « RegionID ».
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember()]
    [RoundtripOriginal()]
    public int RegionID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._regionID;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._regionID != value))
            {
                this.OnRegionIDChanging(value);
                this.RaiseDataMemberChanging("RegionID");
                this.ValidateProperty("RegionID", value);
                this._regionID = value;
                this.RaiseDataMemberChanged("RegionID"); // THIS CAUSE DATAFORM FAIL !!
                this.OnRegionIDChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

The strange things is that if "this.CurrentRegion.Territories" is not empty at the begining, eveything works fine...

What I'am doing wrong ?

The download link of the solution for code details:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=e41cfc4c2d6196d4&resid=E41CFC4C2D6196D4!252&parid=E41CFC4C2D6196D4!215&authkey=!AALulK7qBi40vJk

Lauch solution, go to "regions" page, and then click on the button of the last item on list (with territories equals 0). And then click on cancel on the dataform's childwindows. This should make bug appears.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: I downloaded your solution and it ran fine when I tested it. However, I am using Silverlight 5.

Comment: Hello !  Thanks for your answer ! I try using Silverlight 5. The problem is still here. What did you try exactly ?

Comment: I just opened your project and followed your instructions and didn't get any errors.

Comment: OK, it's very strange... I found the solution now but thank you for your help anyway !

Answer (score 0):

This answer help me to resolve the problem :
[How to apply a Filter to a PagedCollectionView but prevent CollectionChanged event from firing on edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265792/how-to-apply-a-filter-to-a-pagedcollectionview-but-prevent-collectionchanged-eve)

The solution is to not listen to the CollectionChanged event of the PagedCollectionView, but to listen to the CollectionChanged event of the PagedCollectionView.SourceCollection.

So the code become :

```
ObservableCollection<Territory> territories = new ObservableCollection<Territory>(this.CurrentRegion.Territories);
this.RegionTerritories = new PagedCollectionView(territories);
territories.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(RegionTerritories_CollectionChanged);
```

Thanks for help Bryant, and thanks Stackoverflow !